# Any difference between getString() and stringResource()

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

When extracting `string resources`, the default behavior imports the string using `getString()`. However, in the android training website I noticed they used `stringResource()` instead.

My best guess is that they're interchangeable but I can't find any information on when exactly to use one or the other.

**Edit:**
In the training I found an excerpt saying that some Android Studio versions use `getString()` and to replace it with `stringResource()` instead. Still doesn't explain why this happens or why it's important.

Comment: getString() is used for traditional Android development, while stringResource() is used in Jetpack Compose.

Comment: However, you cannot use `stringResource()` at some places, like within services because
```@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function```

Comment: @Yogurt So it is better to use getString() in that sense? [I'm learning Jetpack Compose by the way]

Answer (score 1):

`getString()` is part of the [android Context class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)), it will return the string and replace any formatting with what's defined in Formatter and String.format

`stringResource()` is a part of [androidx compose UI package](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#stringResource(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Array)) & will return the string data associated with the resource

I messed around with it and both seem to take any sort of xml styling I used.

if you're using compose use `stringResource()`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question:

> When exactly to use one or the other?

It depends on the type of project you are working on.
If it is an Android project that uses the old `View` System, then you will not be able to use `stringResource()`, because it is part of the **Compose integration with activity** that comes when you add this dependency inside your `build.gradle` module file:

```
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1")
```

But, if you are developing a **compose** project, then the above dependency will be added by default to your project; that's why you can use either `stringResource()` or `getString()` in a compose project.

Note that `stringResource()` is a `@Composable` function and composable functions can be called from the `setContent()` function or from other composable functions, so if you have a case that you need to call a string resource outside the `setContent()` function or from outside a `@Composable` function, then you will need to use `getString()` function.